# azkaban keeps changing executor id

Tags: azkaban

I'm using Azkaban 3.0 and I have it on a server with two executors. I have a simple echo job that I'm running and I'm specifying the executor by setting the setExecutor=id# in the flow parameters. but whenever I run tise job the execution keeps alternating between the two executors although it explicitly specified in the job definition to run on the second executor only.

Do I need to change something in the configurations? 
I restarted azkaban with executors but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a got a help from a colleague and he showed me how to solve this issue.
it was solved by deleting the executor.port from azkaban webserver properties file.

Answer (score 0):

check this out to know how to  configure azaban with multiple executers. . .
http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/#executor-setup

Comment: thanks for your reply but I already followed the instructions there and it doesn't seem to be working!!